# Windows OpenVPN server, clients can't reach LAN behind server

Tags: openvpn

I`m trying to setup an Windows OpenVPN server to share the network behind this server.

On Linux I've done this several times. However on a Windows server I don't have any luck getting this to work.

I setup the routes and enabled IP forwarding using this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Set the following registry value:
Value Name: IPEnableRouter
Value type: REG_DWORD
Value Data: 1
```

Rebooted the server afterwards.

From the clients, I can reach the server on both LAN IP and OpenVPN IP. However, I cant access any devices in the LAN subnet.

When I run tracert to an IP (not the servers one) in the LAN subnet, I can see its routed through the OpenVPN server.

```
Tracing route to 192.168.30.9 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  SBS [10.9.0.1]
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

OpenVPN server config:

```
 port 1195
 proto udp

 dev tun
 dev-node OVPN

 ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\ca.crt"
 cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.crt"
 key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\server.key"  
 dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\easy-rsa\\keys\\dh1024.pem"

 topology subnet
 server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0

 ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
```

What am I missing here?

```
 push "route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0"
 push "route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0"
 ;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

 duplicate-cn

 keepalive 10 120

 comp-lzo

 persist-key
 persist-tun

 status openvpn-status.log

 verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a static route on your VPN Server LAN default gateway to route VPN packets to the VPN server or use NAT on the server to masquerade VPN packets to the server LAN subnet.